# Apache Spark - datediff for dataframes?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to compute a column based on date difference. Is there a corresponding function for `datediff` that can be used on a column/dataframe? Fe.

```
Column new = old.col("one").divide(old.col("max").minus(old.col("min")));
```

But in this case, the `minus` function doesn't work, because the `min` and `max` columns contain dates. So I need something like datediff for `Column`s. Is there such a thing?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is and it is called `datediff` (`org.apache.spark.sql.functions.datediff`):

```
public static Column datediff(Column end,
              Column start)

Returns the number of days from start to end.

Parameters:
    end - (undocumented)
    start - (undocumented)
Returns:
    (undocumented)
Since:
    1.5.0
```

Example:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local");
       JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        SQLContext sqlContext= new SQLContext(sc);

       DataFrame df = sqlContext.sql(
            "SELECT CAST('2012-01-01' AS DATE), CAST('2013-08-02' AS DATE)").toDF("first", "second");
        df.select(datediff(df.col("first"), df.col("second"))).show();
    }
}
```